# How to make a Hash key with leading digits

Tags: perl

I Need to create a Hash in Perl, where keys start with Digits, like

```
%propertynames = (
2g_values=> "",
3g_values => "",
somethingelse => "",
);
```

If i do it like that, i get an Syntax error. Unfortunately the key names have to be like this. Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only "barewords" are automatically quoted on the left hand side of `=>`. Quote the more complicated strings:

```
%propertynames = (
  '2g_values'     => "",
  '3g_values'     => "",
  'somethingelse' => "", # quotes optional here
);
```

Comment: Thanks, @choroba, for your edit. It completed what I have written.

Comment: ok, i got this wrong and thought keys mustn't be quoted. Perl confuses me sometimes. Thanks a lot